# Post status in Facebook from android device

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I found many explanations on using Facebook SDK, all of which were using an instance of 'Facebook' class like ->

```
Facebook facebookClient = new Facebook();
```

but in the new SDK which I had pulled using Gradle:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
```

I just couldn't find this `Facebook` class. Is there a new update ? Could anyone explain precisely how to go about this in the new SDK ?

Comment: Have you tried https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

Comment: my problem precisely is to share photo along with some texts describing the picture and a link. But it seems "ShareLinkContent" and "SharePhotoContent" are two different entities. Besides there is no content for sharing status. How do I add description to the shared photo? Thank in advance

Comment: seems like the new facebook sdk doesn't permit statuses to be published programmatically at all - maybe due to privacy and security purposes. No wonder why caption wasn't showing when I upload image using the latest 4.2 facebook sdk. If statuses need to be updated, older version of facebook sdk ought to be used I guess. Anyway thanks all :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an extremely old version of the Facebook SDK. The current one uses `Session`, `Request` and `Response` objects to handle third-party API access.

**References:**

**1.** [How to implement Facebook login in Android applications?](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-implement-facebook-login-in-android-applications/).

**EDIT:**

Hit the `Sync Project with Gradle Files` button. Also try re-starting your IDE. It shouldn't be a problem to import this SDK.

Comment: I have installed the same version(via gradle) as told in that link you have provided but still shows red signal in some packages. Is there any difference in copying sdk directly into project folder to installing through gradle? I am using IDEA InteliiJ by the way. Thanks for you answer though.

Comment: Session, Request, and the reference link are all for v3.x of the SDK. The newest release is v4.2, and there has been a major overhaul of a lot of the APIs to make things easier.

Comment: @MingLi exactly but this new api is so complicated. Even as simple as updating a status seems to be a big problem now. Has everything shifted towards graph API already?